# Prevent others from formatting cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have setup a Workbook so that people using it cannot see/use the ribbon or use certain keystroke combinations. However, one of my colleagues managed to Wrap Text on one of the cells. They do not know how they did it and I can't figure it out.

I've sat at their computer and tried to bring up the Wrap Text in ribbon with Alt, H, W, but nothing happened (working as intended). I've tried Ctrl 1, but again, nothing. Here is the code in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.OnKey "^c", ""
Application.OnKey "^v", ""
Application.OnKey "^{INSERT}", ""
Application.OnKey "^{DELETE}", ""
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False
If CD.Range("E6") <> "My Name" Then
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
Else
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
End If



End Sub
```

A similar code restores functions when the workbook is closed.

What have I missed? How did a user enable Wrap Text without right-click menu, access/hotkeys to ribbon or the above keystrokes?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the ribbon go to `Review`
2. Select `Protect Sheet`
3. Check the boxes according to your preferences, then key in the password.

Comment: The sheet is protected. Only unlocked cells can be selected. Everything else is disabled.

Comment: @AzraelJiraco and with settings like that while it's locked they can still edit that are formatted as protected (check format cells to ensure those are indeed locked, not just the sheet)